# Why is the //Windows/Temp temporary file not being created on an http upload?

Tags: perl, upload, dhtml

I'm working on an application on a Windows 10 (current), Apache/2.4.39 (Win64), mod_perl/2.0.10, and Perl/v5.26.3 platform.  The language set is dHTML (html,css,JavaScript, Perl, and C.

I do an http (from Perl) upload and get the temporary file name that is supposed to be created on the server in the //Windows/Temp directory as follows.

```
$upload_filehandle = $page->upload('filex'); # File handle to uploaded file.
my $tmpfilename = $page->tmpFileName( $upload_filehandle );
```

The upload file handle is the correct name of the client file to be uploaded without the client directory (true in the 6 browsers I test in).  And the second line returns a string that looks like the names of other temporary files in the //Windows/Temp directory.  And the temporary file gets created
in the //Windows/Temp directory with the right content.  I know this because I made a copy with a different name.

But the temporary file contents are not loaded into the destination file.
The destination file has the right name in the right place with a correct date/time but has zero bytes.

I'm getting no errors in the Apache log file and no console messages and I'm running with 'use diagnostics;'.   The debugger always has a glob statement that is different each time ( GLOB(0x2a0cc0d06c0) ) that is generated after the upload loop.  And again, A file is created in the right place with the right name and a correct date/time, but with zero bytes.

The write loop to the server destination file follows.  The $filex file name is correct.  The $upload_filehandle is the name of the client file without the directory which translates using tmpFileName (above) to a temporary file on the server in the //Windows/Temp directory that is there with the right content.  But the content is not transferred to the destination file.

```
open(my $UF_fh,'>',$filex) || croak "Couldn't open file $filex, $!"; # Server file to upload to.     

if (index(lc($thefn),'.gif') > -1) {
  binmode($UF_fh); # Set file output to binary mode if image.
}       

while ( <$upload_filehandle> )  {      
  print $UF_fh; # Write it out.
}

close $UF_fh;
```

Any help is appreciated.  Thanks.

ct

Answer (score 0):

One answer that seems to work, but isn't the way it should work.  I have the fully qualified name of the temporary file, so I copy it to the destination file.  The binmode() work is not needed on a copy.  It does work, but I'm still hoping to understand how to make how its supposed to work work.   ct